# Purchased at rates from/at rates ranging from

Tags: prepositions

Question: Does it sound natural with or without "ranging from"? Or should it be omitted?
I've seen examples of sentences with the noun "price" and both variants - with/without "ranging from" - are possible, as far as I've seen.

Context: I want to explain to users that a certain number of projects have been ordered from freelancers within the range of, let's say, $15 - $20 per hour. The sentence will be similar to the following: 30% of {tasks/projects} were ordered at rates *from/ranging from* $10 to $20 per hour.

I'm not sure whether I can find a grammatical rule to apply here, so asking native speakers to confirm which variant (with/without "ranging from" will sound natural to you).

Comment: If I wanted to report facts, I'd say ordered at **rates of $10-20/hour**. If I wanted to stress how variable our costs were, I'd say *rates ranging anywhere from $10 to $20/hour*.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "rules" governing this. However, as "$10 to $20" is a range, "ranging" seems otiose, although not wrong.

Comment: "otiose" is going a bit far, but it's certainly unnecessary.

Comment: I agree:  It is a matter of personal preference.  But it is the most borderline misleading aspect of marketing, along with £99.99.